# Why does my wordpress File Upload not work?

Tags: wordpress, forms, file

```
[file file-uploading limit:500000000 filetypes:gif|png|jpg|jpeg|docx id:fileuploading class:fileuploading]
```

this should be enough for a wordpress file-uploading. Got this with the contact function and just clicked on file-uploading. The form works, you will see the file but you can`t open the document or click on it? What do I have to change for it to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please update your question to include more information. There are dozens of plugins out there that allow file uploads.

Comment: @MarkTruitt What is the best plug in that is free? I only saw good ones where I had to pay for.

Comment: Would really need to know the use case. Contact Form 7 works fine and is free. Just not pretty and requires a bit of CSS hackery.

Answer (score 0):

check the uploads folder permissions is its owned by www-data frist

in ubuntu

```
sudo chown -R /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads www-data:www-data
```